# PDFMiner: How to extract only main text

Tags: python-3.x, pdfminer, pdf-manipulation

I use the following code to convert a PDF to a text file. However, I am only interested in the main text of the document, no figures, no page numbers, no tables, no captions, no formula, etc.

But it give me a bunch of text some of them are short lines extracted from tables or formulas. I want the resulting text be readable for a user without need to stuff which can't be shown in text mode.

The other problem is that it breaks sentences to multiple lines, so I will loose the sentence boundaries. I want to have complete sentences without breaks.

I played with some options like 'all_text = False' with no success.

```
import sys
from tqdm import tqdm
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.converter import XMLConverter, HTMLConverter, TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
import io


def pdfparser(pdf_file):

    fp = open(pdf_file, 'rb')
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = io.StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    laparams.all_texts = False
    laparams.detect_vertical = False
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    # Create a PDF interpreter object.
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    # Process each page contained in the document.
    password = ""
    maxpages = 3
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()
    imagewriter = None
    for page in tqdm(PDFPage.get_pages(fp)):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
        text =  retstr.getvalue()

    text = text.replace("\\n","\n")
    return text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = pdfparser(sys.argv[1])
    print(text)
```

Answer (score 2):

In general this is not directly possible in PDF.

As opposed to e.g. docbook, markdown and restructuredtext, a PDF file does not contain semantic information about the document contents.

That is, the contents are not tagged as e.q. "image", "formula",  "page header", "page footer", "chapter heading", "main text" et cetera.

So you will have to try and *reconstruct* this semantic information from clues in the text. Unfortunately, whether this is possible depends on the document.

For example if the document is structured so that the header and footer are clearly separated from the main text, you could infer from the start position of a string if it is part of the header, footer or main body.

And e.g. font families and sizes might enable you to distinguish between the main text and section or chapter headers and image or table captions. But that is assuming those characteristics are applied consistently.